# get value from NSDictionary not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

1.I get JSON data from web services and add It's to NSDictionary

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

2.Then I Show "dic" in NSLog It's present

```
{"query": [{"IndexNo": 1,"ID": "01","Picture": "img/food-48.png"}]}
```

3.Then I get data value from "dic" in to new NSDictionary "dt"

```
NSDictionary *dt = [dic objectForKey: @"query"];
```

4.Then I Show "dt" in NSLog It's present

```
({ID = 01;IndexNo = 1;Picture = "img/food-48.png";})
```

5.I want to get "ID" from "dt". I use this code

```
NSString *ID = [dt objectForKey: @"ID"];
```

but it's error

```
-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a40a60
```

Comment: is the value of ID is an NSString object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
NSArray *arr = [dic objectForKey: @"query"];
NSDictionary *dt = arr[0];
NSString *ID = [dt objectForKey: @"ID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`[dic objectForKey: @"query"]` returns an NSArray actually. Note these square brackets in the output from the first NSLog statement:

```
{"query": [...]}
```

Try this:

```
NSArray *dtArray = [dic objectForKey: @"query"];
NSDictionary *dt = dtArray[0];
NSString *ID = [dt objectForKey:@"ID"];
```

Or to use the key-value coding behavior of NSDictionary and [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey%3a):

```
NSString *ID = [[dic valueForKeyPath:@"query.ID"] firstObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dt = [[dic objectForKey: @"query"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *ID = [dt objectForKey: @"ID"];
```

You are trying to get value for key from array. change these lines.

Answer (score 0):

From your jsonStructure

```
{"query": [{"IndexNo": 1,"ID": "01","Picture": "img/food-48.png"}]}
```

object for key "query" is an array as {} is a dictionary and [] is an array. so do the following

```
    NSArray *tempArray = [dt objectForKey:@"query"];

    NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *ID = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"ID"];
```

Hope this helps.